# How to remove a specific condition on the where clause (zend framework)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2, where-clause

I have the following query generated by the default library of a third party framework

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "total_rows" FROM "papers" WHERE (papers.paper_trash=0 OR papers.paper_trash IS NULL) AND (paper_category_id='7') AND (qtdavaliacoes='0')
```

I know that if I use a `$query->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);` it will clear the where clause completely, is it possible to clear only the `AND (qtdavaliacoes='0')`condition from it using zend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.other.reset), it is not possible to reset only part of the `WHERE` condition. You would need to either:

- reset the whole `WHERE` condition and add the ones needed ;
- re-instantiate your object and re-build your query all over again.

Comment: Yes, I had to find a way around anyway. /: